# How to get my sales from Amazon on my database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, amazon-web-services

I'm currently developing  an asp.net mvc  inventory website on which I register book orders, etc. I have books already loaded in the database. What I need is to daily update inventory to know each product's current stock. These products are sold in Amazon, therefore I need to get my daily or weekly sales from Amazon to register them into my inventory website.

Which amazon webservice provides me with this information? There are so many on amazon/developers that I got quite confused.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need the [Amazon Marketplace Web Service](https://developer.amazonservices.com/index.html/175-0463561-3478254).